# Can someone help me to choose the best answer to prove the series converges

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Can someone please help me to choose the better answer.

Question :

[image]

**Solution 2)**

[image]

Comment: typo, you forgot the exponent $2$ in the LHS of Cauchy-Schwarz, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Rn

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the first solution
since it is completely self-contained.

The second solution
requires the use
of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
and so it is not self-contained.

Another criteria
for the niceness of a proof
is what generalizations can be proved
by generalizations of the proof.
Both of these proofs
can be generalized,
so I don't know which to prefer
based on this.

Comment: Should i say "an" converges absolutely ?

Comment: Say $\sum |a_n|$ converges or $\sum a_n$ converges absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

To be more precise, you must to see that the series converges absolutely. (the arguments in both solutions are valid if the terms of $(a_{n})$ are eventually nonnegative).

By solution 1, we have $(|a_{n}|-\dfrac{1}{n})^{2}\geq 0$. Then $a_{n}^{2}+\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}\geq 2\dfrac{|a_{n}|}{n}$.

By solution 2, we have $\sum_{n}\dfrac{|a_{n}|}{n}\leq \sqrt{(\sum_{n}a_{n}^{2})}\sqrt{(\sum_{n}\dfrac{1}{n^{2}})}<\infty$.

So, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{|a_{n}|}{n}<\infty$. Therefore, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{a_{n}}{n}$ converges.

Personally, i think both solutions are beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes (marty cohen is right), the first solution has more simplicity: just uses that $\sum_{n}\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}<\infty$ as a non trivial fact, while solution 2 uses this fact and the C-S inequality.

Comment: Should i say "an" converges absolutely ?